# How can I rewrite the polynomial $2x^2 + 10x+6$ as $2x^2 + 7x + 3 + (3x+3)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I got a question wrong because I said there was no way to write $2x^2 + 10x + 6$ as $2x^2 + 7x + 3 + (3x+3)$. How can you write it as such?

I can see that

$$2x^2 + 10x + 6 = 2x^2 + 7x + 3x + 6$$

But I am not seeing how you can go from $2x^2 + 7x + 3x + 6$ to $2x^2 + 7x + 3 + (3x+3)$.

Comment: $6=3+3$, then move around the terms and add some parenthesis in there.

Comment: I supposed to spell it out: $2x^2 + \color{green}{10x} + 6 = 2x^2 + \color{green}{(7x + 3x)} + 6 = 2x^2 + 7x +3x +\color{blue}6 = 2x^2 + 7x +3x + \color{blue}{(3+3)}=2x^2 + 7x + 3x + 3 + 3=2x^2 + 7x +\color{purple}{3x} + \color{purple}3 + 3=2x^2+7x +\color{purple}{(3x+3)} + 3=2x^2+7x+\color{purple}{(3 + 3x)} +3=2x^2 + 7x + 3 + 3x + 3=2x^2+7x+3 +\color{red}{3x+3}=2x^2+7x+3+ \color{red}{(3x+3)} = 2x^2 + 7x +3 + (3x+3)$.  (The colors don't mean anything.  They are only there to draw your attention.)  Basically you can split anything into sums, rearrange the order, and regroup.

Answer (score 1):

We need to use two important properties of addition: associativity and commutativity. That is, for any $a$, $b$ and $c$,

$$\underbrace{a+(b+c)=(a+b)+c}_{\text{associative property}}\quad\text{ and }\quad \underbrace{a+b=b+a}_{\text{commutative property}}.$$

The associative property basically says that you can add/remove parentheses wherever, as long as it is all just addition. The commutative property basically says that you can reorder terms however you'd like, as long as it is all just addition.

Now, notice that $10x=7x+3x$ and $6=3+3$. We have

\begin{align*}
2x^2+10x+6&=2x^2+7x+3x+3+3&\text{by above}\\
&=2x^2+7x+3+3x+3&\text{by commutative property}\\
&=2x^2+7x+3+(3x+3)&\text{by associative property}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$\big(2x^2 + 10x + 6\big)\space - \space 
\big(3x+3\big)\space = \space
\big(2x^2 + 7x + 3\big) $

Adding back we get

$\big(2x^2 + 7x + 3\big)\space + \space
\big(3x+3\big)\space =\space
2x^2 + 7x + 3 +\big(3x+3\big)$